# Selecting all rows whose time spans cover a specific time

Tags: oracle, time

Table rows have a start time column and an end time column. I am searching for any rows whose times exist between 3pm and 4pm.  In other words the row should be included if either: (1) Its start and end were both between 3 and 4, (2) It started before 3 and ended after 4, (3) It started before 3 and ended after 3, (4) It started before 4 and ended after 4. I have tried adding the following where clause to cover those 4 options and it works, but it takes a very long time.  It seems like there must be better code for this.

```
    Where
( 
    (
    (TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  < '15:00:00') 
    and (TO_CHAR(vltecl.patient_out_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                 > '16:00:00')
    )
   or 
   (  (TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  < '16:00:00') 
    and (TO_CHAR(vltecl.patient_out_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                 > '16:00:00')
    )
    or
    (
     (TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  < '15:00:00') 
    and (TO_CHAR(vltecl.patient_out_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                 > '15:00:00')
    )
    or
     ((TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  < '16:00:00') 
    and (TO_CHAR(vltecl.patient_out_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                 > '16:00:00')
    and (TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  > '15:00:00')
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with generic times can be a bit fiddly in oracle (as opposed to a specific time on a specific day).
Approach is generally ok, but it can be simplified a little I think by turning it on it's head.
Basically you want every one which overlaps the hour 3-4, yes?
Well that is anything that didn't end before 3, or started after 4 (Assuming 'out' is always after 'in')

```
Where 
NOT (TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_in_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                  > '16:00:00'
    OR TO_CHAR(vltecl.Patient_OUT_ROOM_DTTM, 'HH24:MI:SS')                 < '15:00:00'
    )
```

I think that works (Not got access to knock up a test right now)

This may still be slow if you are dealing with a lot of data here - even if the In/Out dates are indexed, it has to full scan the table.